# PHPSpreadsheet and Implicit intersection operator: @

Tags: excel, phpspreadsheet

I have  named ranges in my Excel template, and using a formula `=MIN(IF(UnitTypes=T43,Rents))` is being converted to `=MIN(IF(@UnitTypes=T43,Rents))` when I generate my file.  Because of the Implicit intersection operator: @, the formula does not work unless I manually go into each cell and remove the @.

I've tried using: `=MIN(IF(C:C=T43,L:L))` only to have that converted to `=MIN(IF(@C:C=T43,L:L))`

I've also tried setting the named ranges in PHPSpreadsheet with:

```
$spreadsheet->addNamedRange( new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\NamedRange('UnitTypes', $spreadsheet->getSheet(1), 'C15:C38') );
$spreadsheet->addNamedRange( new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\NamedRange('Rents', $spreadsheet->getSheet(1), 'L15:L38') );

$spreadsheet->getSheet(1)->setCellValue('T45','=MIN(IF(UnitTypes=T43,Rents))');
```

But, that generates a #VALUE error, (whereas removing the @ again will work.)

Is there a setting in PHPSpreadsheet to prevent Excel from inserting the Implicit intersection operator?

Comment: Depending on the version of Excel, is MINIFS available?

Comment: I'm using Office 365

Comment: Then use MINIFS.

Comment: That generates an 
Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Exception: Rent Roll !T45 -> Formula Error: Unexpected , in /home/devl3valuation/public_html/cards/templates/src/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Cell.php:274

The formula is good.  I've tried '=MINIFS(Rents, UnitTypes, T43)' and '=MINIFS(L:L, C:C, T43)'

Comment: Hmm - sorry I'm not a PHP guy, not sure what to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was obtained by going into the formula in Excel and holding CTRL=SHIFT=ENTER to surround the formula in {}